# Getting Scrambled text with imap_fetchbody

Tags: php, imap

Good day!

I have 2 emails that I read from my mailbox with IMAP. Those without attachements are going correct, however when a attachement is in the email I get a scrambled text instead of that attachement. Anyone of you know why?

This is what I use to get the bodytext of a mail:

```
    $bodytext = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox, $x, 2));
```

Here is something I would get back (shortend, cause it is very long)

> ÿØÿá.ExifII*Q5ÂÈÚåí(1õ2??'i?8ÔNIKON CORPORATIONNIKON D800ÀÆ-'ÀÆ-'Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows)2016:03:21 12:07:02nolimitpictures(???&"?'?d0?0230.B? V?^? f?n??    ? ?v??90    ¢~¢?¢¢££¤¤¤¤?¤&¤¤¤    ¤ ¤¤1¤?2¤?4¤¾ 2013:06:30 10:51:512013:06:30 10:51:51H¹o@B?i@B | |3?|3?6006671ð ¼   24.0-70.0 mm f/2.8"*(2ôHHÿØÿíAdobe_CMÿîAdobed?ÿÛ?        ÿÀj "ÿÝ ÿÄ?   3!1AQa"q2?¡±B#$RÁb34r?ÑC%?Sðáñcs5¢²?&D?TdE£t6ÒUâeò³?ÃÓuãóF'?¤?´?ÄÔäô¥µÅÕåõVfv??¦¶ÆÖæö7GWgw??§·Ç×ç÷5!1AQaq"2?¡±B#ÁRÑð3$bár??CScs4ñ%¢²?&5ÂÒD?T£dEU6teâò³?ÃÓuãóF?¤?´?ÄÔäô¥µÅÕåõVfv??¦¶ÆÖæö'7GWgw??§·ÇÿÚ?õ4?L÷µ?sÞv± ¹ÄöRRKÍuï«ã31?6d¶?o.?Ã_L´1¸õÉØç{=?öïél@®¾??à1p]?ö?Óm®ØØ?h­¿Ù?5ùwuVÒC?Á×?ýßë¤r=á?§`¨Îqâ<þ?½Gþs¡dDqÈè>X?ÿ5?Öá¿i©§Öþc?§OoY²ê®öz)XlØñ¶?Og;?´ü*^5`>}Ön^ª?Vç°Þå ?ÈÝù?·Ü¦??l   úëøµ²rÚ?OÒ>õ.?×cäxk(É-½òF?Ce?ÿCîÙ{¿Àú?¿óU?:??À?ã#Ïéiü?,ê½L?p?*°?f×%pÈ??H;µ\?¯S)?PvÚv??½?ÿIµYÄê9 ?[Ùn?}ÃúÌ>????k³ µ?>?EbDÍgÚÆX??góñ~?¯?Ó[?-?ØdÔà}Ì#éW¿÷uö~ýj?HDLß÷¢Ò¢d`I?Æ?^?%?Óz?É>?ð?ÁÞoòÿzµ ?  R?¢¤?I9 N?:HRI$???I$§ÿÐõ5??5ô?à??m_+?ÿAËAdýgÝû0??¹ønÿÉ&ä5  yLBòGûÁ??Û ?eicÜÒ{X,l   M´?G±Yûjè]¶8,¬G2¨?¨üUöZËðN^©azo6°CN µ1-iú-º,??öx+    ô¯Ù?ðM½i?cY~ÎØàGÀz?÷?Ô^?¹Ï?>%?ýýË¥A???¹?èô/®9·cab:§m{ó©½?Ë?wò}ªÔ????¹÷ãþ ý©?6

Above scrambled text is because that email has a picture as attachement. What would be the perfect outcome is to have JUST the bodytext and completely ignore the attachement, just something the ,1 plaintext would do. However plaintext is not a option.

I just want the bodytext with html layout, nothing more. The attachement I download later in the script without issues.

Can anyone help me?

Grumpymuppet

Comment: Are you always downloading part 2?  The HTML part is not in a fixed place, it depends on what is in the email.

Comment: It does not really matter if I only download part 2 in this case. The outcome is the same => Scrambled attachement text which I do not want.

Comment: Yes, my point is you SHOULDN'T be downloading part 2.  You need to fetch the bodystructure, and find out where the HTML part is.  It may be part 2.  It may be part 1. It may be part 1.2.  It may be part 1.1.2.  You actually need to check.  You can't make it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using a class that indeed (as mentioned in the comments) looked at what type of mail it is and return that what I need.

The class I use is quite an old one, but it works perfect. I could not use a newer one since we are still using 5.3 (Yes, we are ashamed, but transfering will take a bit longer)

Class I used: https://github.com/benhall14/php-imap-reader